# Test-Path does not find freshly mounted volume

Tags: powershell, mount

I'm using this code in a function to locally mount an encrypted container (using VeraCrypt to letter `I`) and inform user if it was successful. After successfully mounting using `Start-Process`, the `Test-Path` in a loop always fails, even though the same Test-Path returns `True` if tried in another open console. After finishing the script and running `Test-Path 'I:\'` again, it returns `True`.

Why doesn't Test-Path see the newly mounted volume?

```
# mount I:\
Start-Process $veraCrypt '/q /v C:\Users\myuser\container.tc /tc /l I'

# wait 60seconds for mounting
for ($i = 0; $i -lt 60; $i++)
{
    # if I mounted, do other things
    if (Test-Path 'I:\')
    {
        "mounted!"

        break;
    }
    else
    {
        # if not yet mounted, wait
        "not yet... $($i)/60"

        Start-Sleep -Seconds 1   
    }
}
```

Comment: i would remove the for loop...put the `start-sleep -minutes 1` before i test for the path and see if it works.

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you're running `$veraCrypt` asynchronously? If not I'd recommend using `Start-Process -Wait` or (better yet) the call operator (`&`).

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers it works with -Wait. Wanted to run it asynchronously to start other tasks in background, but I'll find another way.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps mounting just takes longer than you waited (although I would expect 60 seconds to be sufficient). If asynchronous execution is not a requirement I'd run the command synchronously, either by adding the parameter `-Wait`

```
Start-Process $veraCrypt '/q /v C:\Users\myuser\container.tc /tc /l I' -Wait
```

or by using the [call operator](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847732.aspx)

```
& "$veraCrypt" /q /v C:\Users\myuser\container.tc /tc /l I
```

If you want to stick with asynchronous execution, a `for` loop isn't the best approach when you don't know the number of loop cycles beforehand. It's usually better to do something like this:

```
$limit = (Get-Date).AddMinutes(5)
do {
  Start-Sleep -Seconds 5
} until ((Test-Path 'I:\') -or (Get-Date) -gt $limit)
```

Comment: Mounting takes just 10-15 seconds (includes writing the password in). I've used for loop to automatically stop after some time (e.g. no to block something indefinitely in case of no input). What really bugs me is why does the path is not found, even though it is for other shells (or after this function).